# How does Chrome load the IP address for a domain that I have blocked in my hosts file?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, windows-8.1, dns

I'm trying to block domains in the `hosts` file, but Chrome is able to load the pages anyways. How is this possible? The blocks have been in place for weeks. I have the option 'Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors' disabled.

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 reddit.com
127.0.0.1 www.reddit.com
```

Somehow I'm also able to ping the domains.

```
$ ping reddit.com

Pinging reddit.com [198.41.208.140] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 198.41.208.140: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=53
```

Comment: Stop DNS client service and disable it

Comment: Did you restart your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you flush your DNS cache? You can do this with the `ipconfig /flushdns` command. If the name is still cached, the system will not try to resolve it, and will never see your entry.